# Upsource: Create review from command line (e.g., with API)

Tags: upsource

Has anyone done this, or know if it is possible with their API?

The API seems accessable from an installed instance: http://yourserver:8888/~api_doc/index.html

Answer (score 0):

It's hidden under a service object as `createReview`, oops.

http://yourserver:8888/~api_doc/reference/Service.html#messages.UpsourceRPC